# perl hash with fat comma

Tags: perl, hash

I have read that using fat comma when defining key value for a hash, we will not need to put `quotes` `''` around the key to indicate that it is a string. However, I found that the if I include `quotes` around the key it still works as if it is ignoring the `''`.

Is the below statement safe to use?

```
$result = { 
     'Bill' => { Java => 56, C => 78, Perl => 90 } , 
     'Mary' => { Java => 82, C => 65, Perl => PX, Python => 72},
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not **NEED** to use single quotes when using the fat comma, you **MAY** if you want to. It is optional.

The fat comma is merely just a comma, the one difference is that if there exists a bareword, a word without quotes, then it will treat that bareword as if it is single quoted.

From [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator):

> The => operator is a synonym for the comma except that it causes a
>   word on its left to be interpreted as a string if it begins with a
>   letter or underscore and is composed only of letters, digits and
>   underscores. This includes operands that might otherwise be
>   interpreted as operators, constants, single number v-strings or
>   function calls. If in doubt about this behavior, the left operand can
>   be quoted explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

It's optional to use quotes `''` with fat comma. With fat comma Perl knows it's a hash key, if you still want to do it explicitly then it's up to you.

With Moose and other semi-keyword libraries using lots of named parameters, you often see code like:

```
has 'name' => (
    is => 'rw',
    isa => 'Str'
);

has 'age' => (
    is => 'rw',
    isa => 'Int'
);
```

There's nothing wrong with that code, but it confuses some people.

Related article by chromatic: [***The Fat Comma and Clarity***](http://www.modernperlbooks.com/mt/2013/04/the-fat-comma-and-clarity.html)